# ERROR: Service 'mysql' failed to build: no matching manifest for linux/arm/v7 in the manifest list entries

Tags: docker, docker-compose, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Docker return me this error

`ERROR: Service 'mysql' failed to build: no matching manifest for linux/arm/v7 in the manifest list entries`
 when build.

I use respbian on Rapsberry Pi 3 B+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the image you are pulling down supports linux/arm/v7  I encountered this on raspberry Pi when I ran docker-compose and it had mysql as a dependency but the image didn't support linux/arm/v7. If you look at the tags for an image, you'll see the OS/ARCH that is support by the image

Comment: What's the image bro?

Comment: This isn’t for any specific image, it applies to any docker image.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by calling "mssql" instead of "MySQL".